# 2 child div, second child div go into new line despite inline-block

Tags: css, html, width, parent-child

Here's the code.

CSS Code:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.child1 {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
.child2 {
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I wanted the child1 and child2 width to be proportional to the parents width. Child1 is 30% of Parent's width while Child2 is 70% of Parent's width. However, the code causes Child2 to enter a new line.

Here's the HTML Code:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">
Hello
</div>
<div class="child2">
Hello
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.epitaxilia.com/test/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `display: inline-block;`, so white-space is an issue there, make your markup like

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
     Hello
    </div><!--
    --><div class="child2">
     Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

<s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8HPYj/)</s> *(The one with issue)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8HPYj/1/) *(Fixed the issue)*

---

There are various ways to sort this out, either you can use `float: left;` for both the elements, but than you will need to `clear` the floats, or you can use `font-size: 0;` on the parent element or you can make the `div` in a single line in your source code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. I was wondering why it wasn't render according to the width I set despite having border-box as the box-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

inline-block is a little tricky and has default margins use floats instead

```
.parent { overflow: hidden; }
.child1 { display: block; float: left; }
.child2 { display: block; float: left; }
```

Comment: You won't need `display: block;` if you `float` your element

Answer (score 0):

Because inline-blocked elements by default have around 4px spacing between each other ( letter spacing )

quick fix

```
.child2 { margin-left:-4px }
```

More info [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Bad solution, change the font-size and it will break

Comment: Possibly why i mentioned it as quick fix and not the ultimate fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Inline block sets the elements on a text baseline, so you'll have some space between the elements the same way you'd have a space between letters on a line of text. Set both the child elements to:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Comment: again, you won't need `display: block;` if you `float` your element

Answer (score 0):

You can float both the child1 and child2 to the left, but that brings with it some other issues.

Inline-Block is a weird property that has some whitespace issues - see http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

So if you rewrite your code, so your child1 and child2 are on the same line, it will work.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">Hello</div><div class="child2">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `vertical-align:top;` for the div which should go to the new line.